# Only change copy of array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm trying to duplicate some items of an array. I change some objects with new id's, the problem is that not only the new array is modified but also the original.

The code I use:

```
function cloneProductLine(oldGroupIndex) {
    // Create new instance of the product lines
    let items = [...productLines];
    let group = items.find((line, index) => index === parseFloat(oldGroupIndex));

    // Get product lines with same parent group Id
    items = items.filter((line) => line.parent_group_id === group.group_id);
    items.forEach((line) => line.parent_group_id = getNewGroupId());

    // Set new Id for group
    group.group_id = getNewGroupId();

    productLines = [...productLines, group, ...items];


    renderProductLine();
  }
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: you need to deep copy your array and work with your cloned array, this might help https://dev.to/samanthaming/how-to-deep-clone-an-array-in-javascript-3cig

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`let items = [...productLines];` creates a shallow array copy. Means all items are the same though the array is new.

You need to create a deeper copy (create new items as well)

Assuming items are plain old objects you could do

```
let items = productLines.map(item => ({...item});
```

Answer (score 1):

Or Simple way

```
let items = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(productLines));
```